# Failed to load keyboard layout DLL for layout A0000409: C:\WINDOWS\system32\kbdPrlUS.dll

Tags: windows, dll, keyboard, gtk, msys2

My ultimate goal is to compile and build a GTK application for Windows using only the C programming language

I'm using a Macbook Pro with the M1 chip. So instead of developing on Mac and cross compiling for windows, I decided to try and develop on Windows for windows.

I'm using parallels to run a Windows 10 virtual machine and after a lot of trial and error I was finally able to compile and execute a GTK program using msys2.

There is just one problem: No keyboard functionality in the GTK application. With the error message in the command prompt: "Failed to load keyboard layout DLL for layout A0000409: C:\WINDOWS\system32\KbdPrlUS.dll"

I solved my previous DLL issue by adding a path to the system variables. How might I approach addressing this keyboard layout DLL issue? The file definitely already exists at that location.

*EDIT* Here is the code that compiles (and works) but doesn't register and letter keypress from the keyboard. The same code works on Mac OS just fine.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static GtkTextBuffer *tb = NULL;
static GtkTextBuffer *tb2 = NULL;


static void
quit_activated(GSimpleAction *action,
               GVariant *parameter,
               gpointer user_data)
{
  GApplication *app = G_APPLICATION (user_data);
  g_application_quit (app);
}

static void
click1_cb (GtkButton *btn,
           gpointer user_data)
{

  GtkTextIter start, end;
  gtk_text_buffer_get_bounds(tb, &start, &end);


  const GtkTextIter* start2 = &start;
  const GtkTextIter* end2 = &end;

  char* text = gtk_text_buffer_get_text(tb,start2,end2,false);


  gtk_text_buffer_set_text (tb2, text, -1);

}

static void
app_activate (GApplication *app,
              gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkWidget *win;
    GtkWidget *tv;
    GtkWidget *tv2;
    GtkWidget *box;
    GtkWidget *btn;
    GtkWidget *btn2;
    gchar *text;

    text =
       "Input some text "
       "As many lines as you want\n"
       "One day, he went into a mountain and found a shining bamboo. "
       "\"What a mysterious bamboo it is!,\" he said. "
       "He cut it, then there was a small cute baby girl in it. "
       "The girl was shining faintly. "
       "He thought this baby girl is a gift from Heaven and took her home.\n"
       "His wife was surprized at his tale. "
       "They were very happy because they had no children. "
       ;

    win = gtk_application_window_new (GTK_APPLICATION (app));
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (win), "Taketori");
    gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (win), 400, 300);

    box = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 10);
    gtk_box_set_homogeneous (GTK_BOX (box), TRUE);
    gtk_window_set_child (GTK_WINDOW (win), box);

    btn = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Execute.");
    g_signal_connect (btn, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (click1_cb), NULL);

    tv = gtk_text_view_new ();
    tv2 = gtk_text_view_new ();
    tb = gtk_text_view_get_buffer (GTK_TEXT_VIEW (tv));
    tb2 = gtk_text_view_get_buffer (GTK_TEXT_VIEW (tv2));
    gtk_text_buffer_set_text (tb2, "", -1);
    gtk_text_buffer_set_text (tb, text, -1);
    gtk_text_view_set_wrap_mode (GTK_TEXT_VIEW (tv), GTK_WRAP_WORD_CHAR);
    gtk_text_view_set_wrap_mode (GTK_TEXT_VIEW (tv2), GTK_WRAP_WORD_CHAR);

    gtk_box_append (GTK_BOX (box),tv);
    gtk_box_append (GTK_BOX (box), tv2);
    gtk_box_append (GTK_BOX (box), btn);

/*
    GSimpleAction *act_quit = g_simple_action_new ("quit", NULL);
    g_action_map_add_action (G_ACTION_MAP (app), G_ACTION(act_quit));
    g_signal_connect (act_quit,"activate",G_CALLBACK (quit_activated),app);

    GMenu *menubar = g_menu_new();
    GMenuItem *menu_item_menu = g_menu_item_new ("Menu",NULL);
    GMenu *menu = g_menu_new();
    GMenuItem *menu_item_quit = g_menu_item_new ("Quit","app.quit");
    g_menu_append_item (menu, menu_item_quit);
    g_object_unref (menu_item_quit);
    g_menu_set_submenu (menu_item_menu,G_MENU_MODEL(menu));
    g_menu_append_item (menubar,menu_item_menu);
    g_object_unref(menu_item_menu);*/

    //gtk_application_set_menubar (GTK_APPLICATION (app), G_MENU_MODEL (menubar));
    //gtk_application_window_set_show_menubar (GTK_APPLICATION_WINDOW (win), TRUE);


    gtk_widget_show (win);

}

int
main (int argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int stat;

  app = gtk_application_new ("com.gitbut.fff", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (app_activate), NULL);
  stat = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);
  return stat;
}
```

Comment: Post minimal example code? A normal Windows program does not touch the keyboard layout.

Comment: I added the code im using.